# Snippets for PyCharm (specifically django templates)

Tags: python, pycharm

I am in the process of moving from SublimeText to PyCharm for python development. One feature I loved in Sublime were the [Djaneiro](https://github.com/squ1b3r/Djaneiro) Django template snippets. In a template, I could just type `include` and it would expand to `{% include "<cursor>" %}`. Is there something like this for PyCharm? Googling didn't reveal anything.

**update**: I started registering the missing tags myself. PyCharm stores these in an XML file so I figured I'd share my efforts [here](https://github.com/chlab/pycharm-django-live-templates).

Comment: Maybe you are looking for 'Live templates'? Under the File>Settings>Editor.

Comment: Well look at that, there are even some django templates, awesome! I wonder why they only have a small subset of all template tags?

Comment: I have no idea. You can make custom ones, though.

Comment: Do you want to copy/paste your comment as answer? Then I'll close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of template snippets in PyCharm is 'Live Templates' under File>Settings>Editor. You can create custom ones by clicking plus on the right. This applies to most IDEs made by Jetbrains.

Comment: Thanks again. I started creating the missing template tags and put them up here: https://github.com/chlab/pycharm-django-live-templates.

Comment: Cheers, good luck.